# React JS, On click Show dropdown for element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My question is about trying to show a static dropdown on click of a span element, But How can i show dropdown only for clicked element(and close the dropdown which is open) without appending any new DOM. Can someone help on this?
What i tried so far is.

```
const SubSubComponent = props => {
  let dropdown = () => {
    if (props.openDropDownFlag) {
      return (
        <ul style={{ listStyle: 'none', border: '1px     solid #000' }}>
          <li>User data </li>
          <li>Edit</li>
        </ul>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span onClick={props.clickHandler}>
        {props.name}
      </span>
      <div>
        {dropdown}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const SubComponent = props => {
  let returnVal = props.list.length
    ? props.list.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <SubSubComponent
            key={index}
            name={item}
            openDropDownFlag={props.openDropDownFlag}
            clickHandler={props.openDropDown}
          />
        );
      })
    : null;

  return (
    <div>
      {returnVal}
    </div>
  );
};

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      arrayList: ['Matt', 'Maxx', 'Newton'],
      openDropDownFlag: false,
    };
    this.openDropDown = this.openDropDown.bind(this);
  }
  openDropDown = () => {
    //code to show dropdown
    debugger;
    this.setState({
      openDropDownFlag: true,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SubComponent
          list={this.state.arrayList}
          openDropDown={this.openDropDown}
          openDropDownFlag={this.state.openDropDownFlag}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I tried the same in [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/VPowom7EO)

Comment: Use codesandbox or snippet and provide a working, minimal example.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried it in sandbox. Here is the link [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/VPowom7EO)

Comment: Is it supposed to work?

Comment: On Click of each user name, The dropdown should open. Tried it by setting a flag in state, But it dint work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your sandbox, I made a simplified version that doesn't involve subcomponents, each time a span is clicked, it updates the state to set the open dropdown list below the span, and since it's only tracking one value for the 'open' list, the already open list disappears.

Sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/BLwl1y6j2

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


class Main extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      arrayList: ['Matt', 'Maxx', 'Newton'],
      open: null
    };
  }

  openList = () => {
    return (
      <ul style={{ listStyle: 'none', border: '1px solid #000' }}>
        <li>User data </li>
        <li>Edit</li>
      </ul>
    );
  }

  openDropDown = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.innerText);
    this.setState({
      open: event.target.innerText,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.arrayList.map((name, index) => {
            return (<div key={`${name}-${index}`}>
            <span onClick={ this.openDropDown }>
              { name }
            </span>
              { name === this.state.open ? this.openList() : null }
          </div>);
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I've written a component like this before, in my experience dropdowns are actually not such an easy task. I had a selection list drop down, which needed to behave consistently when other dropdown lists were positioned near to it, such that the expanded dropdown list view would expand and float over other UI elements when when the dropdown list was clicked. Similarly, it had to prevent clicking on my other dropdown list components nearby while it was expanded, and it had to revert to the non-dropped down mode when I clicked anywhere else on the screen. Additionally it also had to handle click to select an item on the expanded list itself.

To achieve these behaviours involved some layering of invisible absolute and relative positioned div elements with different z-indexes to collect onClick events and react to the different click actions in the UI. Overall it's quite a complex set of interactions.

Comment: Thanks mate. I have got some idea to tackle by going through your solution. Accepting.